# Django ManyToOne relation in serializer get the object who is calling

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

`Hello My code

```
class MyRelatedModel(models.Model):
      related_model_instance = models.ForeignKey(MyModel........)

class MyModel(models.Model)
      [....]
```

serializer

```
class MyRelatedModelSerialzier(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    related_models_instance = MyModelSerializer()
    class Meta:
       model = MyRelatedModel
       fields = ['id', 'name', 'related_model_instance']

class MyModelSerailzier(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    parent_id = serializer.SerializerMethodfield('get_parent_id')
    def get_parent_id():
       # How to get the id of the object which is being serialized?
       # In order to make some calculations
       return 'foo' 
    class Meta:
       model = MyModel
       fields = ['id', 'name', 'parent_id',....
```

## Question

I have 2 models with relation one to Many

In the MyModelSerializer I need to know which is the objects calling, because I need it to calculate some values before returning a response. I thought of overriding to_representation of the MyRelatedSerializer, but it wont work with drf-yasg...

Comment: `related_models_instance = MyModelSerializer()
    class Meta:
       model = MyRelatedModel
       fields = ['id', 'name', 'related_model_instance']`

There's a bug in your code. The field is related_model_instance and the variable above is related_models_instance (There is an extra s after model). This will throw an error, the two need to be the same.

Comment: Inside `MyModelSerailzier` you want `id` of current object being serialized, which one `MyRelatedModel` or `MyModel` and one more thing you mentioned `before returning a response` so it will it be fine if you get id after `creating` the object or you want it before that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyRelatedModelSerialzier(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    related_models_instance = MyModelSerializer(MyRelatedModel)
    class Meta:
       model = MyRelatedModel
       fields = ['id', 'name', 'related_model_instance']

class MyModelSerailzier(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    parent_id = serializer.SerializerMethodfield('get_parent_id')
    def __init__(self, ParentModel):
        self.parent = ParentModel
    def get_parent_id():
       # How to get the id of the object which is being serialized?
       # In order to make some calculations
       return self.parent 
    class Meta:
       model = MyModel
       fields = ['id', 'name', 'parent_id',....
```

This will simply initialize your child model during serialization with the parent model class

Comment: Nice one but i need the instance of the model

Comment: Add an __init__ to MyRelatedModelSerialzier that stores the model instance, then pass it to MyModerSerailzier